# Drupal 7: Sub-path URL aliases work on 'imaginary' aliases like views but not nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, pathauto

Here is my menu structure for a Drupal 7 site.

This works:

```
Home > Depots (views: page) > Depot List (views: page)

aka: '/' > '/depots' > '/depots/depot-list'
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
Home > Careers (node) > Careers List (views: page)

aka: '/' > '/careers' > '/careers/careers-list'

aka: '/' > '/node/123' > '/node/123/careers-list'
```

I can understand why it wouldn't like the whole node/123/subpage as I assume that is reserved for MENU_LOCAL_TASKS such as /edit

So does anyone know, other than converting the node to a view or panels, how I could fix this at all? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the setup, could you clarify some things. What item are you selecting when it doesn't work, Careers or career-list?  What are the settings for Career-List? Does it use contextual filters, if so what are they?

Answer (score 0):

The path is not an override.  The path you enter in the View is the path that loads the view and it must be unique.  Node/123 is already taken.  If you define a view such as Careers/% then the view responds to Career/anything-that-follows, but again you should not have content with the same path.